# angular2-csv: Is it possible to add CSS class?

Tags: angular, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I would like to ask if there is any way to add CSS class in CSV file while I am using angular2-csv. let's say I want to highlight (bold) some specific columns. This package is easy to use but it seems it has some limitation.

```
downloadCSV() {  // Click function
      var data = [
        {
          name: "Name 1",
          age: 13,
          status: 'approved',
        },
        {
          name: 'Name 2',
          age: 11,
          status: 'rejected',
        },
        {
          name: 'Name 3',
          age: 10,
          status: 'pending',
        },
      ];

      var options = {
        title: 'User Details',
        fieldSeparator: ',',
        quoteStrings: '"',
        decimalseparator: '.',
        showLabels: true,
        showTitle: true,
        useBom: true,
        headers: ['Name', 'Age', 'Status']
      };

      new Angular2Csv(data,'filename', options);
    }
```

Comment: No as per documentation there is no such implementation

Comment: That means this package only generate plain CSV file. Thanks for the confirmation. @PardeepJain

Comment: Yes, as per documentation but you can override CSS may be by making changes in package. But this approach is being avoided as it's not so good

Comment: Alright I will look into this. Thanks for the tricks.